$0<k<n$, prove that every continuous map $f:S^k\to S^n$ is null-homotopic
$k,n\in \mathbb Z_{>0}$, $0<k<n$, prove that every continuous map $f:S^k\to S^n$ is null-homotopic.
I know that if $f$ is not surjective, then $f$ is null-homotopic, which is proved in this question Showing that a continuous map $f:X→S^n$
which is not onto is always nullhomotopic.
But I don't know how to prove that $f$ is not surjective.
Moreover I have tried to use Borsuk-Ulam theorem or something related to homology to prove it, but I haven't thought of a solution yet. Could you please give some hints? Many thanks in advance!

You cannot prove that it is not surjective because there are surjective maps $S^1\to S^n$ for all $n\ge 2$. You should prove that your map $f$ is homotopic to a non-surjective map. What tools do you know for proving this?

I have learned Simplicial Homology, Cohomology and Singular Homology this semester. Can I use these to prove this?

Did you learn simplicial or cellular approximation? Do you know how to homotop your map to a smooth map?

Yes,both. How to use simplicial approximation?  The triangulation seems very complex. (Cellullar approximation learned a long time before, so I am a little not familiar)

You can use simplicial or cellular approximation. Your map $f$ is homotopic to a simplicial or cellular map $g : S^k \to S^n$ with respect to suitable triangulations or CW-structures. The nice thing is that you do not need to know them explicitly. In both cases the image of $g$ is contained in the $k$-skeleton of $S^n$ (i.e. the union of all simplices or cells of dimension $\le k$). But the $k$-skeleton is a proper subset of $S^n$, thus $g$ is not surjective.

One proof by induction on $k$ is to first show that the reduced integral homology of the $n$-sphere is concentrated in degree $n$ with $\tilde{H}_n(S^n; \mathbb{Z} ) = \mathbb{Z}$. Then, given $0 < k <n$, supposing the induction hypothesis that $\pi_q(S^n) $ is trivial for all $q <k$, we may apply Hurewicz's Theorem to get an isomorphism $\pi_k(S^n) \cong H_k(S^n; \mathbb{Z} ) =  \tilde{H}_k(S^n; \mathbb{Z} ) = 0$. Thus every continuous map from $S^k$ to $S^n$ is null-homotopic.

Thanks for your answer, however I haven't learned Hurewicz's Theorem and $\pi_q$ yet.
